# How to filter a list by another list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists :

```
List<myObject> mainList;
```

And

```
List<myObject> blackList;
```

I'm trying to make a new list by a condition and another condition that the elements should not be in the blacklist.
Here is my attempt :

```
List<myObject> newList = mainList.Where(x => x.Id == 5 && !blackList.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

This `newList` is generated inside a loop, in the first round of the loop, `blackList` is empty and it works, in the second round `blackList` contains about 200k elements. And when the above line works, it doesn't move next, it stays there for minutes. How can I do filtering more efficiently so that I wouldn't get elements which are in the `blackList`? Thanks.

Comment: Fill a `HashSet<myObject>` instead of a `List<myObject>`. Note that you also have to override `GetHashCode` not only `Equals`(what is recommended anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is due to the way `List<T>` implements `Contains` - it searches linearly through which is quite slow and inefficient for long lists.

To get better performance you could use a better structure for the blacklist - one with a faster/better implementation for long lists like a `HashSet<T>`

```
var blackList = new HashSet<myObject>(theBlackList);
```

Comment: Instead of using the constructor that takes another collection he could fill the hashset directly.

Comment: How will I use hashset in filtering? And how will I add items inside hashset?

Comment: Yes, I just assumed that blacklist comes from an existing list, or database call - and the easiest way to demo that is just pass it to the ctor. @jason no other changes to your code.

Comment: @jason `HasSet` is optimized for the `Contains` function - the only one you use in your code. Since you use a conditional and operator (`&&`) you could also potentially gain some performance by changing the order of the conditions, depending on which one is more likely to be true.